# Creating a random matrix of no duplicates in both row and column from a given set list of elements

Tags: matrix, random, list-manipulation

Say I have a list of letters {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}, I want to create an $4\times 8$ array where each row must not contain duplicates and each column must also not contain duplicates.

Naively writing:

```
gps = CharacterRange["A", "H"];
Table[RandomSample[gps], {4}] // MatrixForm
```

gives you the correct condition that no row may contain duplicates. Take an example below:

$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \text{H} & \text{G} & \text{C} & \text{E} & \text{F} & \text{B} & \text{A} & \text{D} \\
 \text{G} & \text{D} & \text{H} & \text{A} & \text{F} & \text{C} & \text{B} & \text{E} \\
 \text{B} & \text{E} & \text{C} & \text{G} & \text{H} & \text{A} & \text{F} & \text{D} \\
 \text{A} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{F} & \text{H} & \text{B} & \text{G} & \text{E} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Every row is unique, but column 3,5,6,8 all have duplicates.
This is the case most of the time that one column or more will have a duplicate.  Brute force I would just create a while loop that keeps doing random sampling until the more difficult no duplicate in column conditions is met.

This way doesn't really sit well with me. Perhaps there is a fancy use of permutations. Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: Google “Latin rectangle generator Mathematica”.  (Sorry, I’m not at a computer right now to give a more complete answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the conditions that each row must not contain duplicates and each column must not contain duplicates, construct a random solution matrix by rows. The first row is a random sample of the permutations of `gps`. The following rows are selected at random from the remaining permutations that satisfy the conditions.

There are two questions to consider from comments: 1) does the first row determine the rest of the matrix, and 2) is the resulting matrix truly random or does it contain structure and pattern.

Question 1: The first row determines the rest of the solution matrix because each row after the first must be a member of a subset of the permutations of gps, such that no column can match the corresponding column of the previous rows.

To demonstrate the method, consider the set `{A,B,C,D,E}`. Here's a graph that shows how selecting rows at random proceeds from row 1 to row 4.

[image: graph]

Starting with `{A,B,C,D,E}`, there are 44 possibilities for row 2. Selecting `{D,A,B,E,C}` leaves 13 possibilities for row 3. Selecting `{E,C,D,A,B}` leaves 4 possibilities for row 4. Choosing `{C,E,A,B,D}` completes the solution matrix.

> {A,B,C,D,E}
>   {D,A,B,E,C}
>   {E,C,D,A,B}
>   {C,E,A,B,D}

Question 2: The solution matrix cannot be truly random because of the conditions that no row or column contain matches. Rows 2,3,4 are generated from row 1, but row 1 is random. There must be structure and pattern for the following rows because of the condition that there are no matching columns. However, rows 2,3,4 are randomly selected from every possible row that satisfies the conditions given the previous rows. The solution matrix is as random as it can be while satisfying the conditions.

Here's a revised method that replaces my original attempt.

```
perms = StringJoin[#] & /@ Permutations[gps];
rows = {StringJoin[RandomSample[gps]]};
Do[
 regex = StringRiffle[Characters[Last@rows], {"^[^", "][^", "]$"}];
 perms = Flatten@
   DeleteCases[StringCases[perms, RegularExpression[regex]], {}];
 AppendTo[rows, RandomChoice[perms]];
 , 3]
(matrix = Characters[rows]) // MatrixForm
```

The permutations, `perms`, `rows` are saved as strings. Use a regular expression to remove permutations that match any column of the current row. Select a new row from the remaining permutations.

Comment: I interpret OP's question as they want a unifrom _random_ sample of the space of all matrices satisfying the conditions...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The 1,680 possible row rotations are sampled by `RandomSample[Range[0,7],4]`. A random sample of `gps` ensures a selection of all possible rows, so the entire space is sampled, right? Is it a _uniform_ random sample? As I understand the question, it requires a solution that satisfies the conditions I restated.

Comment: Ah, I see. Never mind. (+1)

Comment: This gets the job done, and as you said satisfies the conditions I stated (+1 to that). However, how I view random, is that; in a randomly constructed system, one should not be able to tell how the system was generated. In this answer, the first line is randomly generated, but then, although your do random rotations. I can clearly tell that rows 2,3,4 are generated from 1. This results in there being structure and pattern, something which I would prefer not having. In a sense row 1 determines to some degree the output of the rest of the matrix. Which in my view isn't truly random

Comment: While considering  @LucaPontiggia's comments, I couldn't easily explain my original method and found a different way. I've replaced my original answer.

Comment: @creidhne I must say, this is a lot more in the spirit of what I had in mind, and am slightly ashamed to say I put in less effort to figure this problem out than you have.   I agree with your statement that the very nature of the conditions mean pure randomness does not exist - but, within the scope on my conditional requirements this answer does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[derangementF,  dupeFreeArray]
derangementF = With[{x = Range @ Length @ #, a = #},  a[[#]] & /@ 
 Pick[Permutations[x], Unitize[Times @@@ Function[t, Subtract[#, t]] /@ {##} & @@ 
   Permutations[x]], 1]] &;
dupeFreeArray = Module[{a = {RandomSample @ #}, derangements}, 
 derangements = derangementF[Last @ a];
 Do[AppendTo[a, RandomChoice[derangements = 
   Intersection[derangements, derangementF[Last @ a]]]], {#2 - 1}]; a] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
dfa = dupeFreeArray[CharacterRange["A", "I"], 5]
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ dfa
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  \text{G} & \text{A} & \text{D} & \text{H} & \text{E} & \text{C} & \text{B} & \text{F} & \text{I} \\
>  \text{D} & \text{B} & \text{G} & \text{A} & \text{I} & \text{F} & \text{C} & \text{E} & \text{H} \\
>  \text{A} & \text{I} & \text{F} & \text{B} & \text{D} & \text{H} & \text{E} & \text{C} & \text{G} \\
>  \text{B} & \text{D} & \text{H} & \text{F} & \text{C} & \text{I} & \text{A} & \text{G} & \text{E} \\
>  \text{E} & \text{G} & \text{C} & \text{I} & \text{H} & \text{B} & \text{D} & \text{A} & \text{F} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
And @@ (DuplicateFreeQ /@ Transpose[dfa])
```

> True

```
dfa2 = dupeFreeArray[CharacterRange["A", "I"], 9]
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ dfa2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  \text{I} & \text{D} & \text{G} & \text{B} & \text{F} & \text{A} & \text{H} & \text{C} & \text{E} \\
>  \text{E} & \text{H} & \text{C} & \text{G} & \text{I} & \text{D} & \text{F} & \text{A} & \text{B} \\
>  \text{D} & \text{A} & \text{I} & \text{C} & \text{G} & \text{B} & \text{E} & \text{F} & \text{H} \\
>  \text{C} & \text{B} & \text{F} & \text{H} & \text{E} & \text{G} & \text{A} & \text{D} & \text{I} \\
>  \text{A} & \text{F} & \text{H} & \text{I} & \text{D} & \text{E} & \text{G} & \text{B} & \text{C} \\
>  \text{H} & \text{I} & \text{E} & \text{A} & \text{C} & \text{F} & \text{B} & \text{G} & \text{D} \\
>  \text{G} & \text{E} & \text{B} & \text{D} & \text{A} & \text{I} & \text{C} & \text{H} & \text{F} \\
>  \text{B} & \text{G} & \text{D} & \text{F} & \text{H} & \text{C} & \text{I} & \text{E} & \text{A} \\
>  \text{F} & \text{C} & \text{A} & \text{E} & \text{B} & \text{H} & \text{D} & \text{I} & \text{G} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
And @@ (DuplicateFreeQ /@ Transpose[dfa2])
```

> True

Comment: ... not intended for long lists:)

Answer (score 1):

You are generating Latin rectangles.  Here are three links that might be of interest:

1. [Generate Random Latin squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares)
2. [Latin rectangles from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinRectangle.html)
3. [Latin Square from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html)

Here is a brute force approach that allows for a mixing of numeric and character values:

```
latinRectangle[x0_, rows_] := Module[{n, x},
  n = Length[x0];
  x = ConstantArray[x0, rows];

  (* First row *)
  x[[1]] = RandomSample[x0, n];

  (* Subsequent rows *)
  Do[
   x[[i]] = RandomSample[x0, n];
   While[Length[Select[Flatten[Table[MapThread[Equal, {x[[i]], x[[j]]}], {j, 1, i - 1}]], 
     # == True &]] > 0, x[[i]] = RandomSample[x0, n]], {i, 2, rows}];

  x]

SeedRandom[12345]

latinRectangle[{"1", "A", "C", 4, 5}, 4] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 4 & \text{C} & 5 & \text{A} \\
 \text{C} & 1 & 5 & \text{A} & 4 \\
 4 & \text{C} & \text{A} & 1 & 5 \\
 \text{A} & 5 & 1 & 4 & \text{C} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
latinRectangle[Range[8], 8] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 8 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 \\
 5 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 4 \\
 3 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 1 & 8 \\
 1 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 7 \\
 7 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 5 \\
 2 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 3 \\
 4 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 1 \\
 6 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Here, too, this is not for large lists (like maybe not much bigger than 10).