# Finding all Latin Squares of order 5

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics, algorithm, permutation

A Latin Square is a square of size **n × n** containing numbers **1** to **n** inclusive. Each number occurs once in each row and column.

An example of a 3 × 3 Latin Square is:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Another is:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

My code can work when the order is less than 5

```
n=4;
Dimensions[ans=Permutations[Permutations[Range[n]],{n}]// 
  Select[AllTrue[Join[#,Transpose@#],DuplicateFreeQ]&]]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.947582, {576, 4, 4}}`

When the order is 5, the memory is not enough, I want to know if there is a better way to get all 5×5 Latin squares?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175390/creating-a-random-matrix-of-no-duplicates-in-both-row-and-column-from-a-given-se/181505#181505 .

Comment: The number of Latin Squares rises very quickly with the number of dimensions.  See: [Wolfram Mathworld: Latin Square](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html), which makes the unusual for Mathworld comment about the "**whopping** 576 Latin squares of order 4"

Comment: @Jagra see [OEIS A002860](https://oeis.org/A002860) for the number of latin squares of size $n\le11$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding lines one-by-one and continuing only if the newly added line does not give any column duplications. This highly unoptimized code takes about a minute for $n=5$ (thanks @chyanog for speedup!):

```
addline[lines_] := 
  Select[Append[lines, #] & /@ Permutations[Range[Length[Transpose[lines]]]],
         AllTrue[DuplicateFreeQ]@*Transpose]
latinsquares[n_] := Nest[Join @@ addline /@ # &,
                         Transpose[{Permutations[Range[n]]}],
                         n - 1]

latinsquares[5]
(*    {{{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,1,2},{4,5,2,3,1},{5,3,1,2,4}},
       {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,1,2},{5,3,1,2,4},{4,5,2,3,1}},
       {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,2,1},{4,5,1,3,2},{5,3,2,1,4}},
       ...
       {{5,4,3,2,1},{4,5,2,1,3},{3,2,1,5,4},{2,1,4,3,5},{1,3,5,4,2}}}    *)
```

Comment: `AllTrue[Transpose[#], DuplicateFreeQ]&` is a little faster than `And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ Transpose[#] &`.

Answer (score 6):

If you do a [`"BacktrackSearch"`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BacktrackSearch/) then it will take forever for $n=5$ but use less memory. There are 161280 $5\times5$ Latin squares - I recommend you test this with smaller numbers first like $n=3$:

```
latinQ[mtx_] := 
  AllTrue[mtx, DuplicateFreeQ] && 
   AllTrue[Transpose@mtx, DuplicateFreeQ];

n = 5;
lsquares = ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"][
   ConstantArray[Permutations[Range[n]], n],
   latinQ, latinQ, 161280
];
```

Comment: This can do 5000 n=5 squares per 15 seconds on my machine. It probably gets harder to find the last few solutions that haven't already been encountered, as it will spend more time checking its memory, so expect it to take much longer than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

We can say that a latin square is standard if the first row is [1,...,n] and the first column is also [1,...,n].  Any latin square arises uniquely as follows: take a standard latin square, apply an arbitrary permutation to the full set of n columns, then apply an arbitrary permutation to the last (n-1) rows.  Thus, the number of standard squares is smaller than the full set of squares by a factor n! (n-1)!, which is 2880 in the case n=5.
It is most efficient to find the standard squares by search, and then just apply permutations to get the rest.

If you were using C you could encode everything using bit patterns and then it would only take a few processor cycles worth of bit operations to test the admissibility of each potential new row, which would be extremely fast.  I don't know how well you could do in Mathematica (I'm just a tourist on this particular stackexchange site.)

Answer (score 1):

Since [any group table](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/mathcamp_2012/latin_squares/MC2012_LatinSquares_lecture3.pdf) is a Latin square. But just there is 1 group about 5 orders.

```
FiniteGroupCount[5]
```

> 1

We know it have to be $C_5$. So we can use it to contruct $120$ latin squares with $S_5$:

```
M = Permute[GroupMultiplicationTable[CyclicGroup[5]], SymmetricGroup[5]]
```

> ```
> (*    {{{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,1,2},{4,5,2,3,1},{5,3,1,2,4}},
>        {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,1,2},{5,3,1,2,4},{4,5,2,3,1}},
>        {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,1,4,5,3},{3,4,5,2,1},{4,5,1,3,2},{5,3,2,1,4}},
>        ...
>        {{5,4,3,2,1},{4,5,2,1,3},{3,2,1,5,4},{2,1,4,3,5},{1,3,5,4,2}}}    *)
> ```

Or we just exchange the symbols among them to get $2880$:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Function[{m, cyc}, Permute[#, cyc] & /@ m] @@@ 
  Tuples[{M, GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[5]]}]]
```

It is not all latin squares($161280$) indeed, but it is very faster.

Comment: The question was to find *all* latin squares of a given size.

Comment: @Roman Yes, a multiplication table is a Latin square, but a Latin square is not a multiplication table, which leads it to find only partial Latin squares, but it does find some, and with an efficiency equivalent to that, I think it is still a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[next];
next =
  With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{perms, _Integer, 2}, {rows, _Integer, 2}},
    Table[
     Append[rows, p],
     {p, Select[perms, 
       Catch[Do[If[#[[j]] == rows[[i, j]], Throw@False],
          {i, Length@rows}, {j, Length@#}]; True] &]
      }
     ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]];

n = 5;
perms = Permutations@Range@n;
Nest[Join @@ next[perms, #] &, List /@ perms, n - 1] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.375176, {161280, 5, 5}}